# ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to send an email in MVC 5 application.
I have the email body store in a file called _EmailBody.cshtml

I am following the similar approach described here [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

and I have my setup like this

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

            // viewName is "~/Views/Applications/Emails/_EmailBody.cshtml" 
            // blah blah blah

            return "....";
        }
    }
```

The error happens in this line

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
```

and the error is

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Do you have any idea what is causing the problem?

Thank you

Comment: @CodeCaster, if you know the answer then show it.

Comment: Something is `null`. See the duplicate for debugging hints. Once you find out _what_ is `null`, you can [edit] your question to include your research, as explained in [ask],

Comment: why the debugger doesn't tell you which object is null.